# Using a JavaScript function to get div contents (for slideshow editor)

Tags: javascript, html, function, slideshow

I am attempting to build a slideshow editor. I would like to get the contents of the different divs (title, description, image) in order to place them in a form for the client to edit. I can edit the code of others, but attempting to write my own code is new to me.

I have a function to find the contents of a div and place it in an array. I can't figure out how to use the function. I have a few specific questions.

--How do I define the document that the function is getting the div from. Is there a way to use a variable in order to define the document?
--How do I use what has been retrieved from the function. Do I call the function and then just use the array as I would normally (as in using a loop)?

This is the code I am working with:

```
function getdivHTML(file){
var divArray = file.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(var i=0; i<divArray.length; i++){
    if(divArray[i].className=="image-title") return divArray[i].innerHTML;
}
}
```

If there are any other tips or suggestions, I would be eternally grateful. It was hard enough trying to find the tools to be able to create this function. I have been unable to find any real tips or tutorials on trying to do what I am attempting to do. If something other than JavaScript would be better, I am open to suggestions. If there is a way to edit a slideshow within a text editor (I am using tinymce) that would be even better.

I have edited the code a bit. I have added 'file' as a variable that is passed to the function. Is file something I am able to replace where 'document' usually is?

---

As an example of what the whole file would look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<center><h1>1 Car 1 Story Garages</h1></center>
<div id="gallery" class="content">
    <div id="controls" class="controls"></div>
    <div class="slideshow-container">
        <div id="loading" class="loader"></div>
        <div id="slideshow" class="slideshow"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="caption" class="caption-container"></div>
</div>
<div id="thumbs" class="navigation">

<ul class="thumbs noscript">
    <li>
        <a class="thumb" href="images/garages/1car1story1.png">
            <img src="images/garages/1car1story1.png" alt="1 Car 1 Story Garage 1" height="100px" width="130px" />
        </a>
        <div class="caption">
            <div class="image-title">1 Car 1 Story Garage 1</div>
            <div class="image-desc">12x24 Vinyl A-Frame with optional cupola</div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a class="thumb" href="images/garages/1car1story2.png">
            <img src="images/garages/1car1story2.png" alt="1 Car 1 Story Garage 2" height="100px" width="130px" />
        </a>
        <div class="caption">
            <div class="image-title">1 Car 1 Story Garage 2</div>
            <div class="image-desc">12x24 Duratemp A-Frame w/ optional Stockton glass</div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a class="thumb" href="images/garages/1car1story3.png">
            <img src="images/garages/1car1story3.png" alt="1 Car 1 Story Garage 3" height="100px" width="130px" />
        </a>
        <div class="caption">
            <div class="image-title">1 Car 1 Story Garage 3</div>
            <div class="image-desc">12x24 Vinyl High Wall Dutch Barn</div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a class="thumb" href="images/garages/1car1story4.png">
            <img src="images/garages/1car1story4.png" alt="1 Car 1 Story Garage 4" height="100px" width="130px" />
        </a>
        <div class="caption">
            <div class="image-title">1 Car 1 Story Garage 4</div>
            <div class="image-desc">14x24 Vinyl A-Frame with optional tin roof</div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<hr /><hr />
<script>
var alldivs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    var slides = [];
    var details = [];

    // Find the slides
    for (var i = 0; i < alldivs.length; i++) {
        if (alldivs[i].className.indexOf("slide") != -1) {
            slides.push(alldivs[i]);
        }
    }

    for (var i=0; i<slides.length; i++){
        var slide = slides[i];
        var title = slide.getElementsByClassName("image-title")[0];
        var description = slide.getElementsByClassName("image-desc")[0];
        var image = slide.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];

        details.push({
            "title": title.innerHTML,
            "description": description.innerHTML,
            "image": image.src
        });
    }

    for (i=0;i<details.length;i++){
        document.write(details[i] + "<br >");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `divArray[i].class="image-title"` should be `divArray[i].class=="image-title"` the former is an assignment. Also once you return, you are out of the function.

Comment: `divArray[i].class` won't work, you need to use `divArray[i].className` to access the `class` attribute

Comment: Also the method can be as short as `var divArray = document.getElementsByClassName("image-title");` return divArray && divArray.length ? divArray[0].innerHTML : undefined;`

Comment: I have edited the function, but I'm not sure if 'file' is something I can replace 'document' with. I'm not sure I completely understand your code, Arun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I'm trying to understand your problem...

If you have some HTML with one or more blocks like this:

```
<div class="slide">
    <h2 class="title">Image Title</h2>
    <p class="description">This b da first image.</p>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
</div>
```

You can get the details like this:

```
var alldivs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var slides = [];
var details = [];

// Find the slides
for (var i = 0; i < alldivs.length; i++) {
    if (alldivs[i].className.indexOf("slide") != -1) {
        slides.push(alldivs[i]);
    }
}

for (var i=0; i<slides.length; i++){
    var slide = slides[i];
    var titl = slide.getElementsByClassName("title")[0];
    var description = slide.getElementsByClassName("description")[0];
    var image = slide.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];

    details.push({
        "title": titl.innerHTML,
        "description": description.innerHTML,
        "image": image.src
    });
}
for (var i=0; i<details.length; i++) console.log(details[i].description);
```

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghodmode/C3MEA/)

Is this the information you're looking for?

You should probably use jQuery.  It makes things like this a lot easier.

Comment: You said I should use jQuery. Is the code you gave jQuery or JavaScript. Where you use 'document' in the first line, how do I define what document it is looking at? Is there a way to search in a different file? And how would I display the information from this code? I'm not familiar with 'push' or 'log'.

Comment: @DanielleZarcaro 2 many questions 2 answer in comment, so abbreviated. This code JS only, no jQuery. `document` part of the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM). JS works on loaded page, not files. [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is part of JS. `log` is a method of [`console`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console). Don't think it's standard, but it's usually there. Display info however you want. My example printed to JS console. You could also set it as the `value` of a form element.

Comment: I'm still not sure how to use the function. I place your code inside a function and then call that function? Can it be placed in array instead of console.log so I can then display that array? I have added what my code would look like in my original question.

Comment: `console.log` only shows the information in the JavaScript console.  It's usually only used for debugging and troubleshooting.  The code I've provided stores the info in the details array. You said you wanted to present the information to the user in a form, so you just need to execute the code, then set the values of the related form fields. For example, if your form `input` field for the first title has an id of "title1", you might use `document.getElementById("title1").value(details[0].title);`